# FabricJS - SVG serialization issue

Tags: javascript, svg, fabricjs

There seems to be an issue when trying to serialize a canvas that contains SVG elements. 
I had created the following fiddle:
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/usrrdu/kr7uhb2n/60/)

Initially, I load an SVG from a string. This is working properly, the content is being displayed.

```
fabric.loadSVGFromString(svgString, function(objects, options) {
    var obj = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
    ...
}
```

I added a button which exports the canvas to JSON, the it recreates the initial content using the JSON string.

```
var json = JSON.stringify(canvas);
canvas.loadFromJSON(json);
```

If the button is being pressed, the SVG element is not being displayed correctly anymore, the initial element seems to be broken into several subelements which are not positioned correctly and also their size is changed as well.
For some reason, the content is very small, but it can be seen better if the element is being resized

This issues doesn't occur when using a "simpler" SVG, for instance, an SVG that only contains one symbol.

I'm not sure what the problem is, whether the SVG string contains some elements that are not supported by Fabric, but then why is it being displayed properly the first time?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added back the original width and height to show how to fix the problem. By default Fabric rounds numbers  to do not output giant JSON strings.
Now this measure unit `ex` is not supported ( i have no idea what is it ) and gets parsed as a number. So your SVG is like 2 by 3 pixels.
When saving to JSON all the numbers get rounded to 2 decimals and parsed back you get some approximation errors.

In the snippet below i added an exagerated precision, 80, and that allows you to store and restore correctly.

You can change the number to 3+ to get the right precision you need.

`fabric.Object.NUM_FRACTION_DIGITS = NUMBER`

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');

function loadSVG() {
  fabric.loadSVGFromString(svgString, function(objects, options) {
    var obj = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);

    obj.scaleToWidth(100);
    obj.scaleToHeight(100);
    obj.center();
    canvas.add(obj);
    obj.setCoords();
    canvas.requestRenderAll();
  });
}

fabric.Object.NUM_FRACTION_DIGITS = 80;

document.getElementById('loadBtn').onclick = function(){
 var json = JSON.stringify(canvas);
  canvas.loadFromJSON(json);
};

var svgString = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="3.098ex" height="2.899ex" viewBox="0 -1009.3 1334 1248.3" role="img" focusable="false" style="vertical-align: -0.555ex;">
<defs id="MathJax_SVG_glyphs"><path stroke-width="1" id="MJMATHI-78" d="M52 289Q59 331 106 386T222 442Q257 442 286 424T329 379Q371 442 430 442Q467 442 494 420T522 361Q522 332 508 314T481 292T458 288Q439 288 427 299T415 328Q415 374 465 391Q454 404 425 404Q412 404 406 402Q368 386 350 336Q290 115 290 78Q290 50 306 38T341 26Q378 26 414 59T463 140Q466 150 469 151T485 153H489Q504 153 504 145Q504 144 502 134Q486 77 440 33T333 -11Q263 -11 227 52Q186 -10 133 -10H127Q78 -10 57 16T35 71Q35 103 54 123T99 143Q142 143 142 101Q142 81 130 66T107 46T94 41L91 40Q91 39 97 36T113 29T132 26Q168 26 194 71Q203 87 217 139T245 247T261 313Q266 340 266 352Q266 380 251 392T217 404Q177 404 142 372T93 290Q91 281 88 280T72 278H58Q52 284 52 289Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJMAIN-221A" d="M95 178Q89 178 81 186T72 200T103 230T169 280T207 309Q209 311 212 311H213Q219 311 227 294T281 177Q300 134 312 108L397 -77Q398 -77 501 136T707 565T814 786Q820 800 834 800Q841 800 846 794T853 782V776L620 293L385 -193Q381 -200 366 -200Q357 -200 354 -197Q352 -195 256 15L160 225L144 214Q129 202 113 190T95 178Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJMATHI-61" d="M33 157Q33 258 109 349T280 441Q331 441 370 392Q386 422 416 422Q429 422 439 414T449 394Q449 381 412 234T374 68Q374 43 381 35T402 26Q411 27 422 35Q443 55 463 131Q469 151 473 152Q475 153 483 153H487Q506 153 506 144Q506 138 501 117T481 63T449 13Q436 0 417 -8Q409 -10 393 -10Q359 -10 336 5T306 36L300 51Q299 52 296 50Q294 48 292 46Q233 -10 172 -10Q117 -10 75 30T33 157ZM351 328Q351 334 346 350T323 385T277 405Q242 405 210 374T160 293Q131 214 119 129Q119 126 119 118T118 106Q118 61 136 44T179 26Q217 26 254 59T298 110Q300 114 325 217T351 328Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJMATHI-62" d="M73 647Q73 657 77 670T89 683Q90 683 161 688T234 694Q246 694 246 685T212 542Q204 508 195 472T180 418L176 399Q176 396 182 402Q231 442 283 442Q345 442 383 396T422 280Q422 169 343 79T173 -11Q123 -11 82 27T40 150V159Q40 180 48 217T97 414Q147 611 147 623T109 637Q104 637 101 637H96Q86 637 83 637T76 640T73 647ZM336 325V331Q336 405 275 405Q258 405 240 397T207 376T181 352T163 330L157 322L136 236Q114 150 114 114Q114 66 138 42Q154 26 178 26Q211 26 245 58Q270 81 285 114T318 219Q336 291 336 325Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJMAIN-32" d="M109 429Q82 429 66 447T50 491Q50 562 103 614T235 666Q326 666 387 610T449 465Q449 422 429 383T381 315T301 241Q265 210 201 149L142 93L218 92Q375 92 385 97Q392 99 409 186V189H449V186Q448 183 436 95T421 3V0H50V19V31Q50 38 56 46T86 81Q115 113 136 137Q145 147 170 174T204 211T233 244T261 278T284 308T305 340T320 369T333 401T340 431T343 464Q343 527 309 573T212 619Q179 619 154 602T119 569T109 550Q109 549 114 549Q132 549 151 535T170 489Q170 464 154 447T109 429Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJSZ1-2211" d="M61 748Q64 750 489 750H913L954 640Q965 609 976 579T993 533T999 516H979L959 517Q936 579 886 621T777 682Q724 700 655 705T436 710H319Q183 710 183 709Q186 706 348 484T511 259Q517 250 513 244L490 216Q466 188 420 134T330 27L149 -187Q149 -188 362 -188Q388 -188 436 -188T506 -189Q679 -189 778 -162T936 -43Q946 -27 959 6H999L913 -249L489 -250Q65 -250 62 -248Q56 -246 56 -239Q56 -234 118 -161Q186 -81 245 -11L428 206Q428 207 242 462L57 717L56 728Q56 744 61 748Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJSZ1-220F" d="M158 656Q147 684 131 694Q110 707 69 710H55V750H888V710H874Q840 708 820 698T795 678T786 656V-155Q798 -206 874 -210H888V-250H570V-210H584Q618 -208 638 -197T663 -178T673 -155V710H270V277L271 -155Q283 -206 359 -210H373V-250H55V-210H69Q103 -208 123 -197T148 -178T158 -155V656Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJAMS-4E" d="M20 664Q20 666 31 683H142Q256 683 258 681Q259 680 279 653T342 572T422 468L582 259V425Q582 451 582 490T583 541Q583 611 573 628T522 648Q500 648 493 654Q484 665 493 679L500 683H691Q702 676 702 666Q702 657 698 652Q688 648 680 648Q633 648 627 612Q624 601 624 294V-8Q616 -20 607 -20Q601 -20 596 -15Q593 -13 371 270L156 548L153 319Q153 284 153 234T152 167Q152 103 156 78T172 44T213 34Q236 34 242 28Q253 17 242 3L236 -1H36Q24 6 24 16Q24 34 56 34Q58 35 69 36T86 40T100 50T109 72Q111 83 111 345V603L96 619Q72 643 44 648Q20 648 20 664ZM413 419L240 648H120L136 628Q137 626 361 341T587 54L589 68Q589 78 589 121V192L413 419Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJAMS-5A" d="M39 -1Q29 9 29 12Q29 23 60 77T219 337L410 648H364Q261 648 210 628Q168 612 142 588T109 545T97 509T88 490Q85 489 80 489Q72 489 61 503L70 588Q72 607 75 628T79 662T81 675Q84 677 88 681Q90 683 341 683H592Q604 673 604 666Q604 662 412 348L221 37Q221 35 301 35Q406 35 446 48Q504 68 543 111T597 212Q602 239 617 239Q624 239 629 234T635 223Q635 215 621 113T604 8L597 1Q595 -1 317 -1H39ZM148 637L166 648H112V632Q111 629 110 622T108 612Q108 608 110 608T116 612T129 623T148 637ZM552 646Q552 648 504 648Q452 648 450 643Q448 639 266 343T77 37Q77 35 128 35H179L366 339L552 646ZM572 35Q581 89 581 97L561 77Q542 59 526 48L508 37L539 35H572Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJAMS-51" d="M480 -10Q480 -13 486 -24T507 -50T541 -80T588 -104T648 -114Q666 -114 688 -110T714 -106Q724 -106 728 -114T729 -130Q723 -145 663 -163T548 -181Q503 -181 463 -169T395 -139T343 -97T307 -56T284 -19L280 -3L262 1Q188 24 131 81Q57 155 37 275Q34 292 34 342T37 410Q58 528 131 601Q179 652 248 676T388 701Q485 701 562 661Q698 595 731 448Q742 410 742 341T731 235Q707 141 646 81Q616 50 575 27T493 -5L480 -10ZM568 342Q568 613 437 659L395 666Q329 666 286 626Q232 570 213 439Q210 408 210 342T213 246Q231 113 286 57Q309 37 342 23Q357 19 389 19Q420 19 437 23Q469 38 491 57Q568 134 568 342ZM174 341V354Q174 393 175 419T183 484T205 561T246 635L249 639Q246 639 224 627T193 608Q189 606 183 601T169 589T155 577Q69 491 69 344Q69 133 231 52Q247 42 247 46Q247 46 246 48Q231 69 222 85T200 141T177 239Q174 269 174 341ZM708 341Q708 410 689 467T640 556T588 606T546 630Q532 638 531 638Q530 638 531 635Q563 590 577 543Q602 472 602 341V316Q602 264 599 230T580 144T531 48Q529 44 532 45T546 52Q575 68 596 84T642 128T683 200T706 299Q708 327 708 341ZM391 -17H333Q329 -15 326 -15Q324 -15 324 -17Q324 -21 362 -68Q424 -130 506 -143Q518 -144 544 -144Q569 -144 577 -143L589 -141L575 -139Q544 -127 509 -101T453 -37L442 -19L391 -17Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJAMS-52" d="M17 665Q17 672 28 683H221Q415 681 439 677Q461 673 481 667T516 654T544 639T566 623T584 607T597 592T607 578T614 565T618 554L621 548Q626 530 626 497Q626 447 613 419Q578 348 473 326L455 321Q462 310 473 292T517 226T578 141T637 72T686 35Q705 30 705 16Q705 7 693 -1H510Q503 6 404 159L306 310H268V183Q270 67 271 59Q274 42 291 38Q295 37 319 35Q344 35 353 28Q362 17 353 3L346 -1H28Q16 5 16 16Q16 35 55 35Q96 38 101 52Q106 60 106 341T101 632Q95 645 55 648Q17 648 17 665ZM241 35Q238 42 237 45T235 78T233 163T233 337V621L237 635L244 648H133Q136 641 137 638T139 603T141 517T141 341Q141 131 140 89T134 37Q133 36 133 35H241ZM457 496Q457 540 449 570T425 615T400 634T377 643Q374 643 339 648Q300 648 281 635Q271 628 270 610T268 481V346H284Q327 346 375 352Q421 364 439 392T457 496ZM492 537T492 496T488 427T478 389T469 371T464 361Q464 360 465 360Q469 360 497 370Q593 400 593 495Q593 592 477 630L457 637L461 626Q474 611 488 561Q492 537 492 496ZM464 243Q411 317 410 317Q404 317 401 315Q384 315 370 312H346L526 35H619L606 50Q553 109 464 243Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJAMS-50" d="M16 666Q16 675 28 683H195Q334 683 370 682T437 672Q511 657 554 611T597 495Q597 343 404 309Q402 308 401 308Q381 303 319 303H261V181Q261 157 262 120Q262 60 267 50T304 36Q310 35 313 35Q352 35 352 17Q352 10 346 3L339 -1H28Q16 5 16 16Q16 35 53 35Q68 36 75 37T87 42T95 52Q98 61 98 341T95 630Q91 640 83 643T53 648Q16 648 16 666ZM235 35Q228 46 227 84Q226 129 226 337V621L230 635L237 648H128Q128 647 133 632Q136 620 136 341Q136 64 133 50L128 35H235ZM301 341H313Q339 341 354 344T389 362T417 410T426 498Q426 586 401 616T322 647Q301 647 293 643Q271 637 264 621Q261 617 261 479V341H301ZM429 350Q431 350 443 353T476 367T515 391T548 432T562 490Q562 550 524 592Q507 607 484 619Q481 621 448 635L433 639L439 621Q462 578 462 506Q462 448 454 413T437 366T428 350H429Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJAMS-43" d="M684 131Q684 125 672 109T633 71T573 29T489 -5T386 -19Q330 -19 276 -3T174 46T91 134T44 261Q39 283 39 341T44 421Q66 538 143 611T341 699Q344 699 364 700T395 701Q449 698 503 677T585 655Q603 655 611 662T620 678T625 694T639 702Q650 702 657 690V481L653 474Q640 467 628 472Q624 476 618 496T595 541Q562 587 507 625T390 663H381Q337 663 299 625Q212 547 212 336Q212 249 233 179Q274 30 405 30Q533 30 641 130Q658 147 666 147Q671 147 677 143T684 131ZM250 625Q264 643 261 643Q238 635 214 620T161 579T110 510T79 414Q74 384 74 341T79 268Q89 213 113 169T164 101T217 61T260 39L277 34Q270 41 264 48Q199 111 181 254Q178 281 178 344T181 434Q200 559 250 625ZM621 565V625Q617 623 613 623Q603 619 590 619H575L588 605Q608 583 610 579L621 565Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJMAIN-B1" d="M56 320T56 333T70 353H369V502Q369 651 371 655Q376 666 388 666Q402 666 405 654T409 596V500V353H707Q722 345 722 333Q722 320 707 313H409V40H707Q722 32 722 20T707 0H70Q56 7 56 20T70 40H369V313H70Q56 320 56 333Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJMAIN-221E" d="M55 217Q55 305 111 373T254 442Q342 442 419 381Q457 350 493 303L507 284L514 294Q618 442 747 442Q833 442 888 374T944 214Q944 128 889 59T743 -11Q657 -11 580 50Q542 81 506 128L492 147L485 137Q381 -11 252 -11Q166 -11 111 57T55 217ZM907 217Q907 285 869 341T761 397Q740 397 720 392T682 378T648 359T619 335T594 310T574 285T559 263T548 246L543 238L574 198Q605 158 622 138T664 94T714 61T765 51Q827 51 867 100T907 217ZM92 214Q92 145 131 89T239 33Q357 33 456 193L425 233Q364 312 334 337Q285 380 233 380Q171 380 132 331T92 214Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJMAIN-3D" d="M56 347Q56 360 70 367H707Q722 359 722 347Q722 336 708 328L390 327H72Q56 332 56 347ZM56 153Q56 168 72 173H708Q722 163 722 153Q722 140 707 133H70Q56 140 56 153Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJMAIN-2260" d="M166 -215T159 -215T147 -212T141 -204T139 -197Q139 -190 144 -183L306 133H70Q56 140 56 153Q56 168 72 173H327L406 327H72Q56 332 56 347Q56 360 70 367H426Q597 702 602 707Q605 716 618 716Q625 716 630 712T636 703T638 696Q638 692 471 367H707Q722 359 722 347Q722 336 708 328L451 327L371 173H708Q722 163 722 153Q722 140 707 133H351Q175 -210 170 -212Q166 -215 159 -215Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJMAIN-3E" d="M84 520Q84 528 88 533T96 539L99 540Q106 540 253 471T544 334L687 265Q694 260 694 250T687 235Q685 233 395 96L107 -40H101Q83 -38 83 -20Q83 -19 83 -17Q82 -10 98 -1Q117 9 248 71Q326 108 378 132L626 250L378 368Q90 504 86 509Q84 513 84 520Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJMAIN-3C" d="M694 -11T694 -19T688 -33T678 -40Q671 -40 524 29T234 166L90 235Q83 240 83 250Q83 261 91 266Q664 540 678 540Q681 540 687 534T694 519T687 505Q686 504 417 376L151 250L417 124Q686 -4 687 -5Q694 -11 694 -19Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJMAIN-2264" d="M674 636Q682 636 688 630T694 615T687 601Q686 600 417 472L151 346L399 228Q687 92 691 87Q694 81 694 76Q694 58 676 56H670L382 192Q92 329 90 331Q83 336 83 348Q84 359 96 365Q104 369 382 500T665 634Q669 636 674 636ZM84 -118Q84 -108 99 -98H678Q694 -104 694 -118Q694 -130 679 -138H98Q84 -131 84 -118Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJMAIN-2265" d="M83 616Q83 624 89 630T99 636Q107 636 253 568T543 431T687 361Q694 356 694 346T687 331Q685 329 395 192L107 56H101Q83 58 83 76Q83 77 83 79Q82 86 98 95Q117 105 248 167Q326 204 378 228L626 346L360 472Q291 505 200 548Q112 589 98 597T83 616ZM84 -118Q84 -108 99 -98H678Q694 -104 694 -118Q694 -130 679 -138H98Q84 -131 84 -118Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJMAIN-2248" d="M55 319Q55 360 72 393T114 444T163 472T205 482Q207 482 213 482T223 483Q262 483 296 468T393 413L443 381Q502 346 553 346Q609 346 649 375T694 454Q694 465 698 474T708 483Q722 483 722 452Q722 386 675 338T555 289Q514 289 468 310T388 357T308 404T224 426Q164 426 125 393T83 318Q81 289 69 289Q55 289 55 319ZM55 85Q55 126 72 159T114 210T163 238T205 248Q207 248 213 248T223 249Q262 249 296 234T393 179L443 147Q502 112 553 112Q609 112 649 141T694 220Q694 249 708 249T722 217Q722 153 675 104T555 55Q514 55 468 76T388 123T308 170T224 192Q164 192 125 159T83 84Q80 55 69 55Q55 55 55 85Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJMAIN-2261" d="M56 444Q56 457 70 464H707Q722 456 722 444Q722 430 706 424H72Q56 429 56 444ZM56 237T56 250T70 270H707Q722 262 722 250T707 230H70Q56 237 56 250ZM56 56Q56 71 72 76H706Q722 70 722 56Q722 44 707 36H70Q56 43 56 56Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJMAIN-2200" d="M0 673Q0 684 7 689T20 694Q32 694 38 680T82 567L126 451H430L473 566Q483 593 494 622T512 668T519 685Q524 694 538 694Q556 692 556 674Q556 670 426 329T293 -15Q288 -22 278 -22T263 -15Q260 -11 131 328T0 673ZM414 410Q414 411 278 411T142 410L278 55L414 410Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJMAIN-25B3" d="M75 0L72 2Q69 3 67 5T62 11T59 20Q59 24 62 30Q65 37 245 370T428 707Q428 708 430 710T436 714T444 716Q451 716 455 712Q459 710 644 368L828 27V20Q828 7 814 0H75ZM610 347L444 653Q443 653 278 347T113 40H775Q775 42 610 347Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJMAIN-2207" d="M46 676Q46 679 51 683H781Q786 679 786 676Q786 674 617 326T444 -26Q439 -33 416 -33T388 -26Q385 -22 216 326T46 676ZM697 596Q697 597 445 597T193 596Q195 591 319 336T445 80L697 596Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJMAIN-2208" d="M84 250Q84 372 166 450T360 539Q361 539 377 539T419 540T469 540H568Q583 532 583 520Q583 511 570 501L466 500Q355 499 329 494Q280 482 242 458T183 409T147 354T129 306T124 272V270H568Q583 262 583 250T568 230H124V228Q124 207 134 177T167 112T231 48T328 7Q355 1 466 0H570Q583 -10 583 -20Q583 -32 568 -40H471Q464 -40 446 -40T417 -41Q262 -41 172 45Q84 127 84 250Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJMAIN-222A" d="M591 598H592Q604 598 611 583V376Q611 345 611 296Q610 162 606 148Q605 146 605 145Q586 68 507 23T333 -22Q268 -22 209 -1T106 66T56 173Q55 180 55 384L56 585Q66 598 75 598Q85 598 95 585V378L96 172L98 162Q112 95 181 57T332 18Q415 18 487 58T570 175Q571 180 571 383V583Q579 598 591 598Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJMAIN-2229" d="M88 -21T75 -21T55 -7V200Q55 231 55 280Q56 414 60 428Q61 430 61 431Q77 500 152 549T332 598Q443 598 522 544T610 405Q611 399 611 194V-7Q604 -22 591 -22Q582 -22 572 -9L570 405Q563 433 556 449T529 485Q498 519 445 538T334 558Q251 558 179 518T96 401Q95 396 95 193V-7Q88 -21 75 -21Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJAMS-2205" d="M624 470Q624 468 639 446T668 382T683 291Q683 181 612 99T437 -1Q425 -2 387 -2T337 -1Q245 18 193 70L179 81L131 39Q96 8 89 3T75 -3Q55 -3 55 17Q55 24 61 30T111 73Q154 113 151 113Q151 114 140 130T115 177T95 241Q94 253 94 291T95 341Q112 431 173 495Q265 587 385 587Q410 587 437 581Q522 571 582 513L595 501L642 541Q689 586 695 586Q696 586 697 586T699 587Q706 587 713 583T720 568Q720 560 711 551T664 510Q651 499 642 490T628 475T624 470ZM564 477Q517 522 448 539Q428 546 375 546Q290 546 229 492T144 370Q133 332 133 279Q136 228 151 195Q157 179 168 160T184 141Q186 141 375 307T564 477ZM642 290Q642 318 637 343T625 386T611 416T598 436T593 444Q590 444 402 277T213 108Q213 104 231 89T293 55T392 37Q495 37 568 111T642 290Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJMATHI-3B1" d="M34 156Q34 270 120 356T309 442Q379 442 421 402T478 304Q484 275 485 237V208Q534 282 560 374Q564 388 566 390T582 393Q603 393 603 385Q603 376 594 346T558 261T497 161L486 147L487 123Q489 67 495 47T514 26Q528 28 540 37T557 60Q559 67 562 68T577 70Q597 70 597 62Q597 56 591 43Q579 19 556 5T512 -10H505Q438 -10 414 62L411 69L400 61Q390 53 370 41T325 18T267 -2T203 -11Q124 -11 79 39T34 156ZM208 26Q257 26 306 47T379 90L403 112Q401 255 396 290Q382 405 304 405Q235 405 183 332Q156 292 139 224T121 120Q121 71 146 49T208 26Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJMATHI-3B2" d="M29 -194Q23 -188 23 -186Q23 -183 102 134T186 465Q208 533 243 584T309 658Q365 705 429 705H431Q493 705 533 667T573 570Q573 465 469 396L482 383Q533 332 533 252Q533 139 448 65T257 -10Q227 -10 203 -2T165 17T143 40T131 59T126 65L62 -188Q60 -194 42 -194H29ZM353 431Q392 431 427 419L432 422Q436 426 439 429T449 439T461 453T472 471T484 495T493 524T501 560Q503 569 503 593Q503 611 502 616Q487 667 426 667Q384 667 347 643T286 582T247 514T224 455Q219 439 186 308T152 168Q151 163 151 147Q151 99 173 68Q204 26 260 26Q302 26 349 51T425 137Q441 171 449 214T457 279Q457 337 422 372Q380 358 347 358H337Q258 358 258 389Q258 396 261 403Q275 431 353 431Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJMATHI-3B3" d="M31 249Q11 249 11 258Q11 275 26 304T66 365T129 418T206 441Q233 441 239 440Q287 429 318 386T371 255Q385 195 385 170Q385 166 386 166L398 193Q418 244 443 300T486 391T508 430Q510 431 524 431H537Q543 425 543 422Q543 418 522 378T463 251T391 71Q385 55 378 6T357 -100Q341 -165 330 -190T303 -216Q286 -216 286 -188Q286 -138 340 32L346 51L347 69Q348 79 348 100Q348 257 291 317Q251 355 196 355Q148 355 108 329T51 260Q49 251 47 251Q45 249 31 249Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJMATHI-3B4" d="M195 609Q195 656 227 686T302 717Q319 716 351 709T407 697T433 690Q451 682 451 662Q451 644 438 628T403 612Q382 612 348 641T288 671T249 657T235 628Q235 584 334 463Q401 379 401 292Q401 169 340 80T205 -10H198Q127 -10 83 36T36 153Q36 286 151 382Q191 413 252 434Q252 435 245 449T230 481T214 521T201 566T195 609ZM112 130Q112 83 136 55T204 27Q233 27 256 51T291 111T309 178T316 232Q316 267 309 298T295 344T269 400L259 396Q215 381 183 342T137 256T118 179T112 130Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJMATHI-3F5" d="M227 -11Q149 -11 95 41T40 174Q40 262 87 322Q121 367 173 396T287 430Q289 431 329 431H367Q382 426 382 411Q382 385 341 385H325H312Q191 385 154 277L150 265H327Q340 256 340 246Q340 228 320 219H138V217Q128 187 128 143Q128 77 160 52T231 26Q258 26 284 36T326 57T343 68Q350 68 354 58T358 39Q358 36 357 35Q354 31 337 21T289 0T227 -11Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJMATHI-3B8" d="M35 200Q35 302 74 415T180 610T319 704Q320 704 327 704T339 705Q393 701 423 656Q462 596 462 495Q462 380 417 261T302 66T168 -10H161Q125 -10 99 10T60 63T41 130T35 200ZM383 566Q383 668 330 668Q294 668 260 623T204 521T170 421T157 371Q206 370 254 370L351 371Q352 372 359 404T375 484T383 566ZM113 132Q113 26 166 26Q181 26 198 36T239 74T287 161T335 307L340 324H145Q145 321 136 286T120 208T113 132Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJMATHI-3BC" d="M58 -216Q44 -216 34 -208T23 -186Q23 -176 96 116T173 414Q186 442 219 442Q231 441 239 435T249 423T251 413Q251 401 220 279T187 142Q185 131 185 107V99Q185 26 252 26Q261 26 270 27T287 31T302 38T315 45T327 55T338 65T348 77T356 88T365 100L372 110L408 253Q444 395 448 404Q461 431 491 431Q504 431 512 424T523 412T525 402L449 84Q448 79 448 68Q448 43 455 35T476 26Q485 27 496 35Q517 55 537 131Q543 151 547 152Q549 153 557 153H561Q580 153 580 144Q580 138 575 117T555 63T523 13Q510 0 491 -8Q483 -10 467 -10Q446 -10 429 -4T402 11T385 29T376 44T374 51L368 45Q362 39 350 30T324 12T288 -4T246 -11Q199 -11 153 12L129 -85Q108 -167 104 -180T92 -202Q76 -216 58 -216Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJMATHI-3C0" d="M132 -11Q98 -11 98 22V33L111 61Q186 219 220 334L228 358H196Q158 358 142 355T103 336Q92 329 81 318T62 297T53 285Q51 284 38 284Q19 284 19 294Q19 300 38 329T93 391T164 429Q171 431 389 431Q549 431 553 430Q573 423 573 402Q573 371 541 360Q535 358 472 358H408L405 341Q393 269 393 222Q393 170 402 129T421 65T431 37Q431 20 417 5T381 -10Q370 -10 363 -7T347 17T331 77Q330 86 330 121Q330 170 339 226T357 318T367 358H269L268 354Q268 351 249 275T206 114T175 17Q164 -11 132 -11Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJMATHI-3C1" d="M58 -216Q25 -216 23 -186Q23 -176 73 26T127 234Q143 289 182 341Q252 427 341 441Q343 441 349 441T359 442Q432 442 471 394T510 276Q510 219 486 165T425 74T345 13T266 -10H255H248Q197 -10 165 35L160 41L133 -71Q108 -168 104 -181T92 -202Q76 -216 58 -216ZM424 322Q424 359 407 382T357 405Q322 405 287 376T231 300Q217 269 193 170L176 102Q193 26 260 26Q298 26 334 62Q367 92 389 158T418 266T424 322Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJMATHI-3C3" d="M184 -11Q116 -11 74 34T31 147Q31 247 104 333T274 430Q275 431 414 431H552Q553 430 555 429T559 427T562 425T565 422T567 420T569 416T570 412T571 407T572 401Q572 357 507 357Q500 357 490 357T476 358H416L421 348Q439 310 439 263Q439 153 359 71T184 -11ZM361 278Q361 358 276 358Q152 358 115 184Q114 180 114 178Q106 141 106 117Q106 67 131 47T188 26Q242 26 287 73Q316 103 334 153T356 233T361 278Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJMATHI-3C6" d="M92 210Q92 176 106 149T142 108T185 85T220 72L235 70L237 71L250 112Q268 170 283 211T322 299T370 375T429 423T502 442Q547 442 582 410T618 302Q618 224 575 152T457 35T299 -10Q273 -10 273 -12L266 -48Q260 -83 252 -125T241 -179Q236 -203 215 -212Q204 -218 190 -218Q159 -215 159 -185Q159 -175 214 -2L209 0Q204 2 195 5T173 14T147 28T120 46T94 71T71 103T56 142T50 190Q50 238 76 311T149 431H162Q183 431 183 423Q183 417 175 409Q134 361 114 300T92 210ZM574 278Q574 320 550 344T486 369Q437 369 394 329T323 218Q309 184 295 109L286 64Q304 62 306 62Q423 62 498 131T574 278Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJMATHI-3C9" d="M495 384Q495 406 514 424T555 443Q574 443 589 425T604 364Q604 334 592 278T555 155T483 38T377 -11Q297 -11 267 66Q266 68 260 61Q201 -11 125 -11Q15 -11 15 139Q15 230 56 325T123 434Q135 441 147 436Q160 429 160 418Q160 406 140 379T94 306T62 208Q61 202 61 187Q61 124 85 100T143 76Q201 76 245 129L253 137V156Q258 297 317 297Q348 297 348 261Q348 243 338 213T318 158L308 135Q309 133 310 129T318 115T334 97T358 83T393 76Q456 76 501 148T546 274Q546 305 533 325T508 357T495 384Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJMAIN-27F5" d="M165 270H1510Q1525 262 1525 250T1510 230H165Q167 228 182 216T211 189T244 152T277 96T303 25Q308 7 308 0Q308 -11 288 -11Q281 -11 278 -11T272 -7T267 2T263 21Q245 94 195 151T73 236Q58 242 55 247Q55 254 59 257T73 264Q121 283 158 314T215 375T247 434T264 480L267 497Q269 503 270 505T275 509T288 511Q308 511 308 500Q308 493 303 475Q293 438 278 406T246 352T215 315T185 287T165 270Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJMAIN-27F6" d="M84 237T84 250T98 270H1444Q1328 357 1301 493Q1301 494 1301 496T1300 499Q1300 511 1317 511H1320Q1329 511 1332 510T1338 506T1341 497T1344 481T1352 456Q1374 389 1425 336T1544 261Q1553 258 1553 250Q1553 244 1548 241T1524 231T1486 212Q1445 186 1415 152T1370 85T1349 35T1341 4Q1339 -6 1336 -8T1320 -11Q1300 -11 1300 0Q1300 7 1305 25Q1337 151 1444 230H98Q84 237 84 250Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJMAIN-2193" d="M473 86Q483 86 483 67Q483 63 483 61T483 56T481 53T480 50T478 48T474 47T470 46T464 44Q428 35 391 14T316 -55T264 -168Q264 -170 263 -173T262 -180T261 -184Q259 -194 251 -194Q242 -194 238 -176T221 -121T180 -49Q169 -34 155 -21T125 2T95 20T67 33T44 42T27 47L21 49Q17 53 17 67Q17 87 28 87Q33 87 42 84Q158 52 223 -45L230 -55V312Q230 391 230 482T229 591Q229 662 231 676T243 693Q244 694 251 694Q264 692 270 679V-55L277 -45Q307 1 353 33T430 76T473 86Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJMAIN-2194" d="M263 479Q267 501 271 506T288 511Q308 511 308 500Q308 493 303 475Q293 438 278 406T246 352T215 315T185 287T165 270H835Q729 349 696 475Q691 493 691 500Q691 511 711 511Q720 511 723 510T729 506T732 497T735 481T743 456Q765 389 816 336T935 261Q944 258 944 250Q944 244 939 241T915 231T877 212Q836 186 806 152T761 85T740 35T732 4Q730 -6 727 -8T711 -11Q691 -11 691 0Q691 7 696 25Q728 151 835 230H165Q167 228 182 216T211 189T244 152T277 96T303 25Q308 7 308 0Q308 -11 288 -11Q281 -11 278 -11T272 -7T267 2T263 21Q245 94 195 151T73 236Q58 242 55 247Q55 254 59 257T73 264Q144 292 194 349T263 479Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJMAIN-33" d="M127 463Q100 463 85 480T69 524Q69 579 117 622T233 665Q268 665 277 664Q351 652 390 611T430 522Q430 470 396 421T302 350L299 348Q299 347 308 345T337 336T375 315Q457 262 457 175Q457 96 395 37T238 -22Q158 -22 100 21T42 130Q42 158 60 175T105 193Q133 193 151 175T169 130Q169 119 166 110T159 94T148 82T136 74T126 70T118 67L114 66Q165 21 238 21Q293 21 321 74Q338 107 338 175V195Q338 290 274 322Q259 328 213 329L171 330L168 332Q166 335 166 348Q166 366 174 366Q202 366 232 371Q266 376 294 413T322 525V533Q322 590 287 612Q265 626 240 626Q208 626 181 615T143 592T132 580H135Q138 579 143 578T153 573T165 566T175 555T183 540T186 520Q186 498 172 481T127 463Z"></path></defs>
<g stroke="currentColor" fill="currentColor" stroke-width="0" transform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 0 0)"><use xlink:href="#MJMAIN-221A" x="0" y="37"></use><rect stroke="none" width="500" height="60" x="833" y="778"></rect><use xlink:href="#MJMAIN-33" x="833" y="0"></use></g>
</svg>`;

loadSVG();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.4.3/fabric.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="loadBtn">Convert and load JSON</button>
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="400" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
```

Comment: JFYI, here's what I found on the `ex` unit: *Equivalent to the height of a lower-case letter in the font (and font-size) in effect for an element. If the font doesn’t include lower-case letters, or doesn’t include the metadata about the ex-height, then 1ex = 0.5em.*  -- https://oreillymedia.github.io/Using_SVG/guide/units.html#units-relative-reference

Answer (score 1):

It appears the culprits are the `width` and `height` attributes in your SVG: `width="3.098ex" height="2.899ex"`. Fabric.js is parsing them as `3.098` and `2.899`. It's hard to put my finger on why it's displayed fine before the `toJSON()` and loses some of the scale values after it, but I'm pretty sure it's a bug in the library. On your part, a workaround could be to remove the width and height altogether, then fabric will just take width and height from the viewBox:

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');

function loadSVG() {
  fabric.loadSVGFromString(svgString, function(objects, options) {
    var obj = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);

    obj.scaleToWidth(100);
    obj.scaleToHeight(100);
    obj.center();
    canvas.add(obj);
    obj.setCoords();
    canvas.requestRenderAll();
  });
}

document.getElementById('loadBtn').onclick = function(){
 var json = JSON.stringify(canvas);
  canvas.loadFromJSON(json);
};

var svgString = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 -1009.3 1334 1248.3" role="img" focusable="false" style="vertical-align: -0.555ex;">
<defs id="MathJax_SVG_glyphs"><path stroke-width="1" id="MJMATHI-78" d="M52 289Q59 331 106 386T222 442Q257 442 286 424T329 379Q371 442 430 442Q467 442 494 420T522 361Q522 332 508 314T481 292T458 288Q439 288 427 299T415 328Q415 374 465 391Q454 404 425 404Q412 404 406 402Q368 386 350 336Q290 115 290 78Q290 50 306 38T341 26Q378 26 414 59T463 140Q466 150 469 151T485 153H489Q504 153 504 145Q504 144 502 134Q486 77 440 33T333 -11Q263 -11 227 52Q186 -10 133 -10H127Q78 -10 57 16T35 71Q35 103 54 123T99 143Q142 143 142 101Q142 81 130 66T107 46T94 41L91 40Q91 39 97 36T113 29T132 26Q168 26 194 71Q203 87 217 139T245 247T261 313Q266 340 266 352Q266 380 251 392T217 404Q177 404 142 372T93 290Q91 281 88 280T72 278H58Q52 284 52 289Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJMAIN-221A" d="M95 178Q89 178 81 186T72 200T103 230T169 280T207 309Q209 311 212 311H213Q219 311 227 294T281 177Q300 134 312 108L397 -77Q398 -77 501 136T707 565T814 786Q820 800 834 800Q841 800 846 794T853 782V776L620 293L385 -193Q381 -200 366 -200Q357 -200 354 -197Q352 -195 256 15L160 225L144 214Q129 202 113 190T95 178Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJMATHI-61" d="M33 157Q33 258 109 349T280 441Q331 441 370 392Q386 422 416 422Q429 422 439 414T449 394Q449 381 412 234T374 68Q374 43 381 35T402 26Q411 27 422 35Q443 55 463 131Q469 151 473 152Q475 153 483 153H487Q506 153 506 144Q506 138 501 117T481 63T449 13Q436 0 417 -8Q409 -10 393 -10Q359 -10 336 5T306 36L300 51Q299 52 296 50Q294 48 292 46Q233 -10 172 -10Q117 -10 75 30T33 157ZM351 328Q351 334 346 350T323 385T277 405Q242 405 210 374T160 293Q131 214 119 129Q119 126 119 118T118 106Q118 61 136 44T179 26Q217 26 254 59T298 110Q300 114 325 217T351 328Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJMATHI-62" d="M73 647Q73 657 77 670T89 683Q90 683 161 688T234 694Q246 694 246 685T212 542Q204 508 195 472T180 418L176 399Q176 396 182 402Q231 442 283 442Q345 442 383 396T422 280Q422 169 343 79T173 -11Q123 -11 82 27T40 150V159Q40 180 48 217T97 414Q147 611 147 623T109 637Q104 637 101 637H96Q86 637 83 637T76 640T73 647ZM336 325V331Q336 405 275 405Q258 405 240 397T207 376T181 352T163 330L157 322L136 236Q114 150 114 114Q114 66 138 42Q154 26 178 26Q211 26 245 58Q270 81 285 114T318 219Q336 291 336 325Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJMAIN-32" d="M109 429Q82 429 66 447T50 491Q50 562 103 614T235 666Q326 666 387 610T449 465Q449 422 429 383T381 315T301 241Q265 210 201 149L142 93L218 92Q375 92 385 97Q392 99 409 186V189H449V186Q448 183 436 95T421 3V0H50V19V31Q50 38 56 46T86 81Q115 113 136 137Q145 147 170 174T204 211T233 244T261 278T284 308T305 340T320 369T333 401T340 431T343 464Q343 527 309 573T212 619Q179 619 154 602T119 569T109 550Q109 549 114 549Q132 549 151 535T170 489Q170 464 154 447T109 429Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJSZ1-2211" d="M61 748Q64 750 489 750H913L954 640Q965 609 976 579T993 533T999 516H979L959 517Q936 579 886 621T777 682Q724 700 655 705T436 710H319Q183 710 183 709Q186 706 348 484T511 259Q517 250 513 244L490 216Q466 188 420 134T330 27L149 -187Q149 -188 362 -188Q388 -188 436 -188T506 -189Q679 -189 778 -162T936 -43Q946 -27 959 6H999L913 -249L489 -250Q65 -250 62 -248Q56 -246 56 -239Q56 -234 118 -161Q186 -81 245 -11L428 206Q428 207 242 462L57 717L56 728Q56 744 61 748Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJSZ1-220F" d="M158 656Q147 684 131 694Q110 707 69 710H55V750H888V710H874Q840 708 820 698T795 678T786 656V-155Q798 -206 874 -210H888V-250H570V-210H584Q618 -208 638 -197T663 -178T673 -155V710H270V277L271 -155Q283 -206 359 -210H373V-250H55V-210H69Q103 -208 123 -197T148 -178T158 -155V656Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJAMS-4E" d="M20 664Q20 666 31 683H142Q256 683 258 681Q259 680 279 653T342 572T422 468L582 259V425Q582 451 582 490T583 541Q583 611 573 628T522 648Q500 648 493 654Q484 665 493 679L500 683H691Q702 676 702 666Q702 657 698 652Q688 648 680 648Q633 648 627 612Q624 601 624 294V-8Q616 -20 607 -20Q601 -20 596 -15Q593 -13 371 270L156 548L153 319Q153 284 153 234T152 167Q152 103 156 78T172 44T213 34Q236 34 242 28Q253 17 242 3L236 -1H36Q24 6 24 16Q24 34 56 34Q58 35 69 36T86 40T100 50T109 72Q111 83 111 345V603L96 619Q72 643 44 648Q20 648 20 664ZM413 419L240 648H120L136 628Q137 626 361 341T587 54L589 68Q589 78 589 121V192L413 419Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJAMS-5A" d="M39 -1Q29 9 29 12Q29 23 60 77T219 337L410 648H364Q261 648 210 628Q168 612 142 588T109 545T97 509T88 490Q85 489 80 489Q72 489 61 503L70 588Q72 607 75 628T79 662T81 675Q84 677 88 681Q90 683 341 683H592Q604 673 604 666Q604 662 412 348L221 37Q221 35 301 35Q406 35 446 48Q504 68 543 111T597 212Q602 239 617 239Q624 239 629 234T635 223Q635 215 621 113T604 8L597 1Q595 -1 317 -1H39ZM148 637L166 648H112V632Q111 629 110 622T108 612Q108 608 110 608T116 612T129 623T148 637ZM552 646Q552 648 504 648Q452 648 450 643Q448 639 266 343T77 37Q77 35 128 35H179L366 339L552 646ZM572 35Q581 89 581 97L561 77Q542 59 526 48L508 37L539 35H572Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJAMS-51" d="M480 -10Q480 -13 486 -24T507 -50T541 -80T588 -104T648 -114Q666 -114 688 -110T714 -106Q724 -106 728 -114T729 -130Q723 -145 663 -163T548 -181Q503 -181 463 -169T395 -139T343 -97T307 -56T284 -19L280 -3L262 1Q188 24 131 81Q57 155 37 275Q34 292 34 342T37 410Q58 528 131 601Q179 652 248 676T388 701Q485 701 562 661Q698 595 731 448Q742 410 742 341T731 235Q707 141 646 81Q616 50 575 27T493 -5L480 -10ZM568 342Q568 613 437 659L395 666Q329 666 286 626Q232 570 213 439Q210 408 210 342T213 246Q231 113 286 57Q309 37 342 23Q357 19 389 19Q420 19 437 23Q469 38 491 57Q568 134 568 342ZM174 341V354Q174 393 175 419T183 484T205 561T246 635L249 639Q246 639 224 627T193 608Q189 606 183 601T169 589T155 577Q69 491 69 344Q69 133 231 52Q247 42 247 46Q247 46 246 48Q231 69 222 85T200 141T177 239Q174 269 174 341ZM708 341Q708 410 689 467T640 556T588 606T546 630Q532 638 531 638Q530 638 531 635Q563 590 577 543Q602 472 602 341V316Q602 264 599 230T580 144T531 48Q529 44 532 45T546 52Q575 68 596 84T642 128T683 200T706 299Q708 327 708 341ZM391 -17H333Q329 -15 326 -15Q324 -15 324 -17Q324 -21 362 -68Q424 -130 506 -143Q518 -144 544 -144Q569 -144 577 -143L589 -141L575 -139Q544 -127 509 -101T453 -37L442 -19L391 -17Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJAMS-52" d="M17 665Q17 672 28 683H221Q415 681 439 677Q461 673 481 667T516 654T544 639T566 623T584 607T597 592T607 578T614 565T618 554L621 548Q626 530 626 497Q626 447 613 419Q578 348 473 326L455 321Q462 310 473 292T517 226T578 141T637 72T686 35Q705 30 705 16Q705 7 693 -1H510Q503 6 404 159L306 310H268V183Q270 67 271 59Q274 42 291 38Q295 37 319 35Q344 35 353 28Q362 17 353 3L346 -1H28Q16 5 16 16Q16 35 55 35Q96 38 101 52Q106 60 106 341T101 632Q95 645 55 648Q17 648 17 665ZM241 35Q238 42 237 45T235 78T233 163T233 337V621L237 635L244 648H133Q136 641 137 638T139 603T141 517T141 341Q141 131 140 89T134 37Q133 36 133 35H241ZM457 496Q457 540 449 570T425 615T400 634T377 643Q374 643 339 648Q300 648 281 635Q271 628 270 610T268 481V346H284Q327 346 375 352Q421 364 439 392T457 496ZM492 537T492 496T488 427T478 389T469 371T464 361Q464 360 465 360Q469 360 497 370Q593 400 593 495Q593 592 477 630L457 637L461 626Q474 611 488 561Q492 537 492 496ZM464 243Q411 317 410 317Q404 317 401 315Q384 315 370 312H346L526 35H619L606 50Q553 109 464 243Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJAMS-50" d="M16 666Q16 675 28 683H195Q334 683 370 682T437 672Q511 657 554 611T597 495Q597 343 404 309Q402 308 401 308Q381 303 319 303H261V181Q261 157 262 120Q262 60 267 50T304 36Q310 35 313 35Q352 35 352 17Q352 10 346 3L339 -1H28Q16 5 16 16Q16 35 53 35Q68 36 75 37T87 42T95 52Q98 61 98 341T95 630Q91 640 83 643T53 648Q16 648 16 666ZM235 35Q228 46 227 84Q226 129 226 337V621L230 635L237 648H128Q128 647 133 632Q136 620 136 341Q136 64 133 50L128 35H235ZM301 341H313Q339 341 354 344T389 362T417 410T426 498Q426 586 401 616T322 647Q301 647 293 643Q271 637 264 621Q261 617 261 479V341H301ZM429 350Q431 350 443 353T476 367T515 391T548 432T562 490Q562 550 524 592Q507 607 484 619Q481 621 448 635L433 639L439 621Q462 578 462 506Q462 448 454 413T437 366T428 350H429Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJAMS-43" d="M684 131Q684 125 672 109T633 71T573 29T489 -5T386 -19Q330 -19 276 -3T174 46T91 134T44 261Q39 283 39 341T44 421Q66 538 143 611T341 699Q344 699 364 700T395 701Q449 698 503 677T585 655Q603 655 611 662T620 678T625 694T639 702Q650 702 657 690V481L653 474Q640 467 628 472Q624 476 618 496T595 541Q562 587 507 625T390 663H381Q337 663 299 625Q212 547 212 336Q212 249 233 179Q274 30 405 30Q533 30 641 130Q658 147 666 147Q671 147 677 143T684 131ZM250 625Q264 643 261 643Q238 635 214 620T161 579T110 510T79 414Q74 384 74 341T79 268Q89 213 113 169T164 101T217 61T260 39L277 34Q270 41 264 48Q199 111 181 254Q178 281 178 344T181 434Q200 559 250 625ZM621 565V625Q617 623 613 623Q603 619 590 619H575L588 605Q608 583 610 579L621 565Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJMAIN-B1" d="M56 320T56 333T70 353H369V502Q369 651 371 655Q376 666 388 666Q402 666 405 654T409 596V500V353H707Q722 345 722 333Q722 320 707 313H409V40H707Q722 32 722 20T707 0H70Q56 7 56 20T70 40H369V313H70Q56 320 56 333Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJMAIN-221E" d="M55 217Q55 305 111 373T254 442Q342 442 419 381Q457 350 493 303L507 284L514 294Q618 442 747 442Q833 442 888 374T944 214Q944 128 889 59T743 -11Q657 -11 580 50Q542 81 506 128L492 147L485 137Q381 -11 252 -11Q166 -11 111 57T55 217ZM907 217Q907 285 869 341T761 397Q740 397 720 392T682 378T648 359T619 335T594 310T574 285T559 263T548 246L543 238L574 198Q605 158 622 138T664 94T714 61T765 51Q827 51 867 100T907 217ZM92 214Q92 145 131 89T239 33Q357 33 456 193L425 233Q364 312 334 337Q285 380 233 380Q171 380 132 331T92 214Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJMAIN-3D" d="M56 347Q56 360 70 367H707Q722 359 722 347Q722 336 708 328L390 327H72Q56 332 56 347ZM56 153Q56 168 72 173H708Q722 163 722 153Q722 140 707 133H70Q56 140 56 153Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJMAIN-2260" d="M166 -215T159 -215T147 -212T141 -204T139 -197Q139 -190 144 -183L306 133H70Q56 140 56 153Q56 168 72 173H327L406 327H72Q56 332 56 347Q56 360 70 367H426Q597 702 602 707Q605 716 618 716Q625 716 630 712T636 703T638 696Q638 692 471 367H707Q722 359 722 347Q722 336 708 328L451 327L371 173H708Q722 163 722 153Q722 140 707 133H351Q175 -210 170 -212Q166 -215 159 -215Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJMAIN-3E" d="M84 520Q84 528 88 533T96 539L99 540Q106 540 253 471T544 334L687 265Q694 260 694 250T687 235Q685 233 395 96L107 -40H101Q83 -38 83 -20Q83 -19 83 -17Q82 -10 98 -1Q117 9 248 71Q326 108 378 132L626 250L378 368Q90 504 86 509Q84 513 84 520Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJMAIN-3C" d="M694 -11T694 -19T688 -33T678 -40Q671 -40 524 29T234 166L90 235Q83 240 83 250Q83 261 91 266Q664 540 678 540Q681 540 687 534T694 519T687 505Q686 504 417 376L151 250L417 124Q686 -4 687 -5Q694 -11 694 -19Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJMAIN-2264" d="M674 636Q682 636 688 630T694 615T687 601Q686 600 417 472L151 346L399 228Q687 92 691 87Q694 81 694 76Q694 58 676 56H670L382 192Q92 329 90 331Q83 336 83 348Q84 359 96 365Q104 369 382 500T665 634Q669 636 674 636ZM84 -118Q84 -108 99 -98H678Q694 -104 694 -118Q694 -130 679 -138H98Q84 -131 84 -118Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJMAIN-2265" d="M83 616Q83 624 89 630T99 636Q107 636 253 568T543 431T687 361Q694 356 694 346T687 331Q685 329 395 192L107 56H101Q83 58 83 76Q83 77 83 79Q82 86 98 95Q117 105 248 167Q326 204 378 228L626 346L360 472Q291 505 200 548Q112 589 98 597T83 616ZM84 -118Q84 -108 99 -98H678Q694 -104 694 -118Q694 -130 679 -138H98Q84 -131 84 -118Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJMAIN-2248" d="M55 319Q55 360 72 393T114 444T163 472T205 482Q207 482 213 482T223 483Q262 483 296 468T393 413L443 381Q502 346 553 346Q609 346 649 375T694 454Q694 465 698 474T708 483Q722 483 722 452Q722 386 675 338T555 289Q514 289 468 310T388 357T308 404T224 426Q164 426 125 393T83 318Q81 289 69 289Q55 289 55 319ZM55 85Q55 126 72 159T114 210T163 238T205 248Q207 248 213 248T223 249Q262 249 296 234T393 179L443 147Q502 112 553 112Q609 112 649 141T694 220Q694 249 708 249T722 217Q722 153 675 104T555 55Q514 55 468 76T388 123T308 170T224 192Q164 192 125 159T83 84Q80 55 69 55Q55 55 55 85Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJMAIN-2261" d="M56 444Q56 457 70 464H707Q722 456 722 444Q722 430 706 424H72Q56 429 56 444ZM56 237T56 250T70 270H707Q722 262 722 250T707 230H70Q56 237 56 250ZM56 56Q56 71 72 76H706Q722 70 722 56Q722 44 707 36H70Q56 43 56 56Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJMAIN-2200" d="M0 673Q0 684 7 689T20 694Q32 694 38 680T82 567L126 451H430L473 566Q483 593 494 622T512 668T519 685Q524 694 538 694Q556 692 556 674Q556 670 426 329T293 -15Q288 -22 278 -22T263 -15Q260 -11 131 328T0 673ZM414 410Q414 411 278 411T142 410L278 55L414 410Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJMAIN-25B3" d="M75 0L72 2Q69 3 67 5T62 11T59 20Q59 24 62 30Q65 37 245 370T428 707Q428 708 430 710T436 714T444 716Q451 716 455 712Q459 710 644 368L828 27V20Q828 7 814 0H75ZM610 347L444 653Q443 653 278 347T113 40H775Q775 42 610 347Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJMAIN-2207" d="M46 676Q46 679 51 683H781Q786 679 786 676Q786 674 617 326T444 -26Q439 -33 416 -33T388 -26Q385 -22 216 326T46 676ZM697 596Q697 597 445 597T193 596Q195 591 319 336T445 80L697 596Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJMAIN-2208" d="M84 250Q84 372 166 450T360 539Q361 539 377 539T419 540T469 540H568Q583 532 583 520Q583 511 570 501L466 500Q355 499 329 494Q280 482 242 458T183 409T147 354T129 306T124 272V270H568Q583 262 583 250T568 230H124V228Q124 207 134 177T167 112T231 48T328 7Q355 1 466 0H570Q583 -10 583 -20Q583 -32 568 -40H471Q464 -40 446 -40T417 -41Q262 -41 172 45Q84 127 84 250Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJMAIN-222A" d="M591 598H592Q604 598 611 583V376Q611 345 611 296Q610 162 606 148Q605 146 605 145Q586 68 507 23T333 -22Q268 -22 209 -1T106 66T56 173Q55 180 55 384L56 585Q66 598 75 598Q85 598 95 585V378L96 172L98 162Q112 95 181 57T332 18Q415 18 487 58T570 175Q571 180 571 383V583Q579 598 591 598Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJMAIN-2229" d="M88 -21T75 -21T55 -7V200Q55 231 55 280Q56 414 60 428Q61 430 61 431Q77 500 152 549T332 598Q443 598 522 544T610 405Q611 399 611 194V-7Q604 -22 591 -22Q582 -22 572 -9L570 405Q563 433 556 449T529 485Q498 519 445 538T334 558Q251 558 179 518T96 401Q95 396 95 193V-7Q88 -21 75 -21Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJAMS-2205" d="M624 470Q624 468 639 446T668 382T683 291Q683 181 612 99T437 -1Q425 -2 387 -2T337 -1Q245 18 193 70L179 81L131 39Q96 8 89 3T75 -3Q55 -3 55 17Q55 24 61 30T111 73Q154 113 151 113Q151 114 140 130T115 177T95 241Q94 253 94 291T95 341Q112 431 173 495Q265 587 385 587Q410 587 437 581Q522 571 582 513L595 501L642 541Q689 586 695 586Q696 586 697 586T699 587Q706 587 713 583T720 568Q720 560 711 551T664 510Q651 499 642 490T628 475T624 470ZM564 477Q517 522 448 539Q428 546 375 546Q290 546 229 492T144 370Q133 332 133 279Q136 228 151 195Q157 179 168 160T184 141Q186 141 375 307T564 477ZM642 290Q642 318 637 343T625 386T611 416T598 436T593 444Q590 444 402 277T213 108Q213 104 231 89T293 55T392 37Q495 37 568 111T642 290Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJMATHI-3B1" d="M34 156Q34 270 120 356T309 442Q379 442 421 402T478 304Q484 275 485 237V208Q534 282 560 374Q564 388 566 390T582 393Q603 393 603 385Q603 376 594 346T558 261T497 161L486 147L487 123Q489 67 495 47T514 26Q528 28 540 37T557 60Q559 67 562 68T577 70Q597 70 597 62Q597 56 591 43Q579 19 556 5T512 -10H505Q438 -10 414 62L411 69L400 61Q390 53 370 41T325 18T267 -2T203 -11Q124 -11 79 39T34 156ZM208 26Q257 26 306 47T379 90L403 112Q401 255 396 290Q382 405 304 405Q235 405 183 332Q156 292 139 224T121 120Q121 71 146 49T208 26Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJMATHI-3B2" d="M29 -194Q23 -188 23 -186Q23 -183 102 134T186 465Q208 533 243 584T309 658Q365 705 429 705H431Q493 705 533 667T573 570Q573 465 469 396L482 383Q533 332 533 252Q533 139 448 65T257 -10Q227 -10 203 -2T165 17T143 40T131 59T126 65L62 -188Q60 -194 42 -194H29ZM353 431Q392 431 427 419L432 422Q436 426 439 429T449 439T461 453T472 471T484 495T493 524T501 560Q503 569 503 593Q503 611 502 616Q487 667 426 667Q384 667 347 643T286 582T247 514T224 455Q219 439 186 308T152 168Q151 163 151 147Q151 99 173 68Q204 26 260 26Q302 26 349 51T425 137Q441 171 449 214T457 279Q457 337 422 372Q380 358 347 358H337Q258 358 258 389Q258 396 261 403Q275 431 353 431Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJMATHI-3B3" d="M31 249Q11 249 11 258Q11 275 26 304T66 365T129 418T206 441Q233 441 239 440Q287 429 318 386T371 255Q385 195 385 170Q385 166 386 166L398 193Q418 244 443 300T486 391T508 430Q510 431 524 431H537Q543 425 543 422Q543 418 522 378T463 251T391 71Q385 55 378 6T357 -100Q341 -165 330 -190T303 -216Q286 -216 286 -188Q286 -138 340 32L346 51L347 69Q348 79 348 100Q348 257 291 317Q251 355 196 355Q148 355 108 329T51 260Q49 251 47 251Q45 249 31 249Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJMATHI-3B4" d="M195 609Q195 656 227 686T302 717Q319 716 351 709T407 697T433 690Q451 682 451 662Q451 644 438 628T403 612Q382 612 348 641T288 671T249 657T235 628Q235 584 334 463Q401 379 401 292Q401 169 340 80T205 -10H198Q127 -10 83 36T36 153Q36 286 151 382Q191 413 252 434Q252 435 245 449T230 481T214 521T201 566T195 609ZM112 130Q112 83 136 55T204 27Q233 27 256 51T291 111T309 178T316 232Q316 267 309 298T295 344T269 400L259 396Q215 381 183 342T137 256T118 179T112 130Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJMATHI-3F5" d="M227 -11Q149 -11 95 41T40 174Q40 262 87 322Q121 367 173 396T287 430Q289 431 329 431H367Q382 426 382 411Q382 385 341 385H325H312Q191 385 154 277L150 265H327Q340 256 340 246Q340 228 320 219H138V217Q128 187 128 143Q128 77 160 52T231 26Q258 26 284 36T326 57T343 68Q350 68 354 58T358 39Q358 36 357 35Q354 31 337 21T289 0T227 -11Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJMATHI-3B8" d="M35 200Q35 302 74 415T180 610T319 704Q320 704 327 704T339 705Q393 701 423 656Q462 596 462 495Q462 380 417 261T302 66T168 -10H161Q125 -10 99 10T60 63T41 130T35 200ZM383 566Q383 668 330 668Q294 668 260 623T204 521T170 421T157 371Q206 370 254 370L351 371Q352 372 359 404T375 484T383 566ZM113 132Q113 26 166 26Q181 26 198 36T239 74T287 161T335 307L340 324H145Q145 321 136 286T120 208T113 132Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJMATHI-3BC" d="M58 -216Q44 -216 34 -208T23 -186Q23 -176 96 116T173 414Q186 442 219 442Q231 441 239 435T249 423T251 413Q251 401 220 279T187 142Q185 131 185 107V99Q185 26 252 26Q261 26 270 27T287 31T302 38T315 45T327 55T338 65T348 77T356 88T365 100L372 110L408 253Q444 395 448 404Q461 431 491 431Q504 431 512 424T523 412T525 402L449 84Q448 79 448 68Q448 43 455 35T476 26Q485 27 496 35Q517 55 537 131Q543 151 547 152Q549 153 557 153H561Q580 153 580 144Q580 138 575 117T555 63T523 13Q510 0 491 -8Q483 -10 467 -10Q446 -10 429 -4T402 11T385 29T376 44T374 51L368 45Q362 39 350 30T324 12T288 -4T246 -11Q199 -11 153 12L129 -85Q108 -167 104 -180T92 -202Q76 -216 58 -216Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJMATHI-3C0" d="M132 -11Q98 -11 98 22V33L111 61Q186 219 220 334L228 358H196Q158 358 142 355T103 336Q92 329 81 318T62 297T53 285Q51 284 38 284Q19 284 19 294Q19 300 38 329T93 391T164 429Q171 431 389 431Q549 431 553 430Q573 423 573 402Q573 371 541 360Q535 358 472 358H408L405 341Q393 269 393 222Q393 170 402 129T421 65T431 37Q431 20 417 5T381 -10Q370 -10 363 -7T347 17T331 77Q330 86 330 121Q330 170 339 226T357 318T367 358H269L268 354Q268 351 249 275T206 114T175 17Q164 -11 132 -11Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJMATHI-3C1" d="M58 -216Q25 -216 23 -186Q23 -176 73 26T127 234Q143 289 182 341Q252 427 341 441Q343 441 349 441T359 442Q432 442 471 394T510 276Q510 219 486 165T425 74T345 13T266 -10H255H248Q197 -10 165 35L160 41L133 -71Q108 -168 104 -181T92 -202Q76 -216 58 -216ZM424 322Q424 359 407 382T357 405Q322 405 287 376T231 300Q217 269 193 170L176 102Q193 26 260 26Q298 26 334 62Q367 92 389 158T418 266T424 322Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJMATHI-3C3" d="M184 -11Q116 -11 74 34T31 147Q31 247 104 333T274 430Q275 431 414 431H552Q553 430 555 429T559 427T562 425T565 422T567 420T569 416T570 412T571 407T572 401Q572 357 507 357Q500 357 490 357T476 358H416L421 348Q439 310 439 263Q439 153 359 71T184 -11ZM361 278Q361 358 276 358Q152 358 115 184Q114 180 114 178Q106 141 106 117Q106 67 131 47T188 26Q242 26 287 73Q316 103 334 153T356 233T361 278Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJMATHI-3C6" d="M92 210Q92 176 106 149T142 108T185 85T220 72L235 70L237 71L250 112Q268 170 283 211T322 299T370 375T429 423T502 442Q547 442 582 410T618 302Q618 224 575 152T457 35T299 -10Q273 -10 273 -12L266 -48Q260 -83 252 -125T241 -179Q236 -203 215 -212Q204 -218 190 -218Q159 -215 159 -185Q159 -175 214 -2L209 0Q204 2 195 5T173 14T147 28T120 46T94 71T71 103T56 142T50 190Q50 238 76 311T149 431H162Q183 431 183 423Q183 417 175 409Q134 361 114 300T92 210ZM574 278Q574 320 550 344T486 369Q437 369 394 329T323 218Q309 184 295 109L286 64Q304 62 306 62Q423 62 498 131T574 278Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJMATHI-3C9" d="M495 384Q495 406 514 424T555 443Q574 443 589 425T604 364Q604 334 592 278T555 155T483 38T377 -11Q297 -11 267 66Q266 68 260 61Q201 -11 125 -11Q15 -11 15 139Q15 230 56 325T123 434Q135 441 147 436Q160 429 160 418Q160 406 140 379T94 306T62 208Q61 202 61 187Q61 124 85 100T143 76Q201 76 245 129L253 137V156Q258 297 317 297Q348 297 348 261Q348 243 338 213T318 158L308 135Q309 133 310 129T318 115T334 97T358 83T393 76Q456 76 501 148T546 274Q546 305 533 325T508 357T495 384Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJMAIN-27F5" d="M165 270H1510Q1525 262 1525 250T1510 230H165Q167 228 182 216T211 189T244 152T277 96T303 25Q308 7 308 0Q308 -11 288 -11Q281 -11 278 -11T272 -7T267 2T263 21Q245 94 195 151T73 236Q58 242 55 247Q55 254 59 257T73 264Q121 283 158 314T215 375T247 434T264 480L267 497Q269 503 270 505T275 509T288 511Q308 511 308 500Q308 493 303 475Q293 438 278 406T246 352T215 315T185 287T165 270Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJMAIN-27F6" d="M84 237T84 250T98 270H1444Q1328 357 1301 493Q1301 494 1301 496T1300 499Q1300 511 1317 511H1320Q1329 511 1332 510T1338 506T1341 497T1344 481T1352 456Q1374 389 1425 336T1544 261Q1553 258 1553 250Q1553 244 1548 241T1524 231T1486 212Q1445 186 1415 152T1370 85T1349 35T1341 4Q1339 -6 1336 -8T1320 -11Q1300 -11 1300 0Q1300 7 1305 25Q1337 151 1444 230H98Q84 237 84 250Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJMAIN-2193" d="M473 86Q483 86 483 67Q483 63 483 61T483 56T481 53T480 50T478 48T474 47T470 46T464 44Q428 35 391 14T316 -55T264 -168Q264 -170 263 -173T262 -180T261 -184Q259 -194 251 -194Q242 -194 238 -176T221 -121T180 -49Q169 -34 155 -21T125 2T95 20T67 33T44 42T27 47L21 49Q17 53 17 67Q17 87 28 87Q33 87 42 84Q158 52 223 -45L230 -55V312Q230 391 230 482T229 591Q229 662 231 676T243 693Q244 694 251 694Q264 692 270 679V-55L277 -45Q307 1 353 33T430 76T473 86Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJMAIN-2194" d="M263 479Q267 501 271 506T288 511Q308 511 308 500Q308 493 303 475Q293 438 278 406T246 352T215 315T185 287T165 270H835Q729 349 696 475Q691 493 691 500Q691 511 711 511Q720 511 723 510T729 506T732 497T735 481T743 456Q765 389 816 336T935 261Q944 258 944 250Q944 244 939 241T915 231T877 212Q836 186 806 152T761 85T740 35T732 4Q730 -6 727 -8T711 -11Q691 -11 691 0Q691 7 696 25Q728 151 835 230H165Q167 228 182 216T211 189T244 152T277 96T303 25Q308 7 308 0Q308 -11 288 -11Q281 -11 278 -11T272 -7T267 2T263 21Q245 94 195 151T73 236Q58 242 55 247Q55 254 59 257T73 264Q144 292 194 349T263 479Z"></path><path stroke-width="1" id="MJMAIN-33" d="M127 463Q100 463 85 480T69 524Q69 579 117 622T233 665Q268 665 277 664Q351 652 390 611T430 522Q430 470 396 421T302 350L299 348Q299 347 308 345T337 336T375 315Q457 262 457 175Q457 96 395 37T238 -22Q158 -22 100 21T42 130Q42 158 60 175T105 193Q133 193 151 175T169 130Q169 119 166 110T159 94T148 82T136 74T126 70T118 67L114 66Q165 21 238 21Q293 21 321 74Q338 107 338 175V195Q338 290 274 322Q259 328 213 329L171 330L168 332Q166 335 166 348Q166 366 174 366Q202 366 232 371Q266 376 294 413T322 525V533Q322 590 287 612Q265 626 240 626Q208 626 181 615T143 592T132 580H135Q138 579 143 578T153 573T165 566T175 555T183 540T186 520Q186 498 172 481T127 463Z"></path></defs>
<g stroke="currentColor" fill="currentColor" stroke-width="0" transform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 0 0)"><use xlink:href="#MJMAIN-221A" x="0" y="37"></use><rect stroke="none" width="500" height="60" x="833" y="778"></rect><use xlink:href="#MJMAIN-33" x="833" y="0"></use></g>
</svg>`;

loadSVG();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.4.3/fabric.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="loadBtn">Convert and load JSON</button>
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="400" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
```